# Null covariance between X and Y: non-linear relationship between them

Tags: random-variables, covariance

Let us consider a variable X with values $\{-1,1\}$, and another one Y with values $\{-2,-1,1,2\}$.

X and Y have the following joint probability function $P(x,y)$:

[image]

From this table, the covariance is zero.

Does this mean that there are no linear relationships between X and Y (because covariance function should measures linear relationships)?

Then, is it possible to calculate the non linear relation between X and Y **or, at least, prove that their relationship is non linear**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, $y$ takes the values $\pm\left(\frac{3}{2}x-\frac{1}{2}\right)$ with equal probabilities. Since $y$ take both positive and negative values with equal probabilities, we can't say that $y$ increases or decreases with $x$. However, it is not possible to deduce such relationships easily, for a general case.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I edited my post...

Comment: Can we prove that the relationship is non linear? I mean, even without knowing this relation...

Comment: What do you mean by non-linear: $Y\neq aX+b$ ?

Comment: Yes I mean this.

Comment: Such a relation holds only if for every value of $X$, there exists a unique value of $Y$. For a general case where there is a one-to-one correspondence between $X$ and$Y$, it is easy to verify if a such linear relation holds.